# A library uses the same package as this project

Tags: android-studio

For 2 days, I have been trying to fix my Android Studio setup, but despite a lot of googling have had no luck fixing this problem. Gradle keeps giving me the error

> Error:Execution failed for task ':Android-Tabbedout-30:processQaReleaseResources'.
>
> Error: A library uses the same package as this project
>     You can temporarily disable this error with android.enforceUniquePackageName=false
>     However, this is temporary and will be enforced in 1.0

If I add in the enforceUniquePackageName=false to the gradle file, then the project can be successively refreshed by Gradle, but once I try to run it I get this error:

> Error Code:
>       2
>     Output:
>       UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>       com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: What are the package names?

Comment: Please include your build files in your question.

Comment: having same problem. have you found a solution?

Answer (score 3):

I was searching for that same problem and i find this on github

https://github.com/DWorkS/AStickyHeader/issues/12

And this solved my problem.

All this says is to rename the package name on the `AndroidManifast.xml` file.
And its done.